# Searching in Hashcode doesn't work in Java

Tags: java, set, containers, hashset

I Have a

```
Set tablica = new HashSet();
```

And I want to search it so I wrote something like this:

```
public void searchStudentbySurname() {
    int a = tablica.size();
    if (0 >= a) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No data");
    } else {
        String S = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Give me a surname");
        Iterator itr = tablica.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String str = (String) itr.next();
            if(tablica.equals(S)) {    // this if doesn't work (1)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

I want to know why (1) doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you looping at all? Why not just use `if (tablica.contains(S))`? (Not that `S` is a good local variable name, by the way...)

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a String to a Set, so it's can't return true.

You probably meant to compare it to `str` - `str.equals(S)`, but even that is not necessary.
You can simply replace the entire while loop with `tablica.contains(S)`. That's what `Set`s are for.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare the item in tablica to the user input.

Should be:

```
if(str.equals(S)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(tablica.equals(S))
```

doesn't work because you are comparing objects of 2 different types (Set and String). You can use contains that

> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e
>   such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).